# Как через условие проверить загрузил пользователь картинку или нет?

Tags: php, html

Как проверить загрузил пользователь картинку или нет? вот кусочки кода:
PHP

```
  $path = 'images/' . time() . $_FILES['photo']['name'];

   if (!isset($path)){
    mysqli_query($connect, "UPDATE `Акции` SET `photo`='$path' WHERE `id` = '$nomer'");
```

HTML

```
form action="adminphoto.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <label>Фотография</label>
            <input type="file" name="photo">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!-- Тип кодирования данных, enctype, ДОЛЖЕН БЫТЬ указан ИМЕННО так -->
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="**adminphoto.php**" method="POST">
    <!-- Поле MAX_FILE_SIZE должно быть указано до поля загрузки файла -->
    <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="30000" />
    <!-- Название элемента input определяет имя в массиве $_FILES -->
    Отправить этот файл: <input name="userfile" type="file" />
    <input type="submit" value="Отправить файл" />
</form>

<?php
$uploaddir = '**images**';
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . time() . basename($_FILES['userfile']['name']);

echo '<pre>';
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
    echo "Файл корректен и был успешно загружен.\n";
} else {
    echo "Возможная атака с помощью файловой загрузки!\n";
}

echo 'Некоторая отладочная информация:';
print_r($_FILES);

print "</pre>";

?>
```

Источник: https://www.php.net/manual/ru/features.file-upload.post-method.php